# jQueryでREST APIを呼び、レスポンスを取得する方法

Tags: jquery, paypal, ajax, rest

現在、jQueryからREST APIを呼び結果を取得するコードを書いています。

【やりたいこと】
　Paypalの以下のサンドボックス用のURLにjQueryでアクセスする。
　https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

結果は以下の文字列が返ってくるのでそれをjQueryで取得したい。
　ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

【質問】
　http://semooh.jp/jquery/api/ajax/jQuery.ajax/options/

上記のマニュアルを参考に以下のコードを書いて見ましたが、どうしてもレスポンスの文字列を取得することができずにエラーのfunctionに入ってしまいます。

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery REST API sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>PaypalのデータをRest型のAPIで取得した後、jQuaryを利用し表示する</h2>

<h2>$ajax で読み込む</h2>
<ul class="ajax"></ul>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
        dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function(text){
            var len = text.length;
            alert("success : " + len);
            for(var i=0; i < len; i++){
                $(".ajax").append('<li><a href="'+text[i].link+'">'+text[i].title+'</a></li>');
            }
    }).fail(function(text){
            var len = text.length;
            alert("error : " + len);
            $('.ajax').append("読み込みませんでした。");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

何が原因かどなたかご教授いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

jsでほかのサーバーにあるファイルを読みだすことは原則できません。（クロスドメイン問題）
phpなどで取得してjsで情報を受け取り処理、は可能です。

[JS：クロスドメインでAjax通信 | ARTICLE | goma](http://www.goma.pw/article/2015-03-14-2/)

Comment: Eaiさん
同サーバーのプログラムから取得する場合はきちんと動き、外部APIから取得する場合はエラーになることを確認しました。
基本的なことを失念しておりました。
ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

すいません、今回の質問の本質的問題ではないかと思いますが、PayPalのREST APIのエンドポイントは

https://api.sandbox.paypal.com

で

https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

は、NVP（Classic）APIと呼ばれるものです。

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#api-operations

REST APIのリクエストとレスポンスはJSONそのままになっています。

以上、補足まで。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにその通りですね。先日気がついたのですが、NVP(Classic)APIはURLにパラメータをつけてリクエストを送って呼び出すためREST APIであると勘違いしておりました。